# Распознавание речи. Kaldi. Установка kaldi-asr

Tags: python, распознавание-речи, kaldi

Пытаюсь установить kaldi-asr с помощью команды `pip install py-kaldi-asr` (туториал https://pypi.org/project/py-kaldi-asr/).

Предварительно, по требованию, установила Cython
 (`pip install Cython`) и заголовки ATLAS (`sudo apt install libatlas-dev`).

Однако при попытке запустить установку `pip install py-kaldi-asr` вылетает ошибка

```
$ pip install py-kaldi-asr
Collecting py-kaldi-asr
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/b5/bb/0082185cfa67d63068358de9b1a65661c8dcdbe97e935809427d5881ea17/py-kaldi-asr-0.5.2.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Package atlas was not found in the pkg-config search path.
    Perhaps you should add the directory containing `atlas.pc'
    to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
    No package 'atlas' found
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-install-u_2wcks2/py-kaldi-asr/setup.py", line 99, in <module>
        **find_dependencies()),
      File "/tmp/pip-install-u_2wcks2/py-kaldi-asr/setup.py", line 46, in find_dependencies
        raise Exception ('Failed to find libatlas.so.3 on your system.')
    Exception: Failed to find libatlas.so.3 on your system.
    looking for atlas library, trying pkg-config first...
    looking for atlas library, trying hard-coded paths...

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-u_2wcks2/py-kaldi-asr/
```

Подскажите, как это решить?

Дополнительно: как работать с Kaldi? Есть хорошие туториалы?

Спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Начиная с [этой строчки](https://github.com/gooofy/py-kaldi-asr/blob/08ec4a4ab3a3051fc560de9d40f5888277f88ac1/setup.py#L41) в setup.py исправить пути к библиотекам atlas, они лежат в /usr/lib/libatlas-base в Ubuntu и называются немного по-другому.

A atlas.pc называется blas-atlas.pc в Ubuntu.

Вообще сейчас есть библиотеки, которые проще устанавливаются, вроде https://github.com/alphacep/vosk-api, устанавливается просто `pip install vosk`